# Break out of Loop but Still make Loop Useable

Tags: python, loops

I'm a beginner to Python, so this might sound pretty easy.

Anyway, I'm a little confused on when to use `break`, `pass`, or `continue`. I want to have a loop where it breaks out of it,  but then after all the code runs again, then the loop will run again. This is some example code:

```
score = 100
while True:
    score + 1
    # break, continue, or pass

score - 30
```

Basically, what I want to happen is have score go up by 1, then have it go down by 30, and then keep going up by 1.

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put *another* loop around this then? That way you can loop the subtraction too.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
score = 100
first = True
while True:
    while True:
        score += 1
        if first:
            first = False
            break
    score -= 30
```